# Java MySql databse creation

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a small online cinema ticket shop for university. Using springboot, java and mysql.
I have a problem with the initial database creation. I will put all the code below. The problem I have is with creating table users. I can't spot the mistake since the table is the same as the others. Another problem I have is that I'm using a composite key in one of my tables so that table and the related ones aren't altering as should.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
                          user_id CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                          fullname CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                          email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
                          username VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                          password VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL ,
                          permission INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                          CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE seats (
                           seat_id CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                           seat_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
                           seat_letter CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
                           CONSTRAINT pk_seats PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE theaters (
                           theater_id CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                           name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                           location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                           number_of_halls INTEGER NOT NULL,
                           CONSTRAINT pk_theaters PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE movies (
                         movie_id CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                         name CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                         description VARCHAR (120)  NULL,
                         length VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                         CONSTRAINT pk_movies PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tickets (
                      ticket_id CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                      reserve_or_buy CHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                      id_user CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                      seat_projection_connection CHAR (50) NULL,/*kako dupli kljuc zapisat*/
                      CONSTRAINT pk_tickets PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE halls (
                                hall_id  CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                                name CHAR NULL,
                                number_of_seats INTEGER NULL,
                                description VARCHAR (120) NULL,
                                id_theater CHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
                                CONSTRAINT pk_halls PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE projections (
                       projection_id CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                       date CHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                       start_time CHAR (25) NOT NULL ,
                       id_hall CHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
                       id_movie CHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
                       CONSTRAINT pk_projections PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
                             id CHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
                             id_projection CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                             id_seat CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                             id_ticket CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                             status CHAR (25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "empty",
                             CONSTRAINT pk_connections PRIMARY KEY (projection_id, seat_id) /*sta stavit posto je slozeni kljuc*/
);

ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT uc_users_username UNIQUE (username);

ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT uc_users_email UNIQUE (email);

ALTER TABLE tickets ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ON_TICKETS FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES tickets (ticket_id);

ALTER TABLE halls ADD CONSTRAINT FK_THEATER_ON_HALL FOREIGN KEY (id_theater) REFERENCES halls (hall_id);

ALTER TABLE projections ADD CONSTRAINT FK_HALL_ON_PROJECTION FOREIGN KEY (id_hall) REFERENCES projections (projection_id);

ALTER TABLE projections ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MOVIE_ON_PROJECTION FOREIGN KEY (id_movie) REFERENCES projections (projection_id);

ALTER TABLE connections ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CONNECTION_ON_PROJECTION FOREIGN KEY (id_projection) REFERENCES projections (projection_id);

ALTER TABLE connections ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CONNECTION_ON_SEAT FOREIGN KEY (id_seat) REFERENCES seats (seat_id);

ALTER TABLE connections ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TICKET_ON_CONNECTION FOREIGN KEY (id_ticket) REFERENCES tickets (ticket_id);


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID userId;

    @Column(name = "fullname",nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name ="username", nullable = false )
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "0")
    private Integer permission;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Ticket> ticketList;


}


@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID ticketId;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String reserveOrBuy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "seat"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "projection")
    })
    private SeatProjectionConnection seatProjectionConnection;
}


@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "projections")
public class Projection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID projectionId;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "startTime", nullable = false)
    private String startTime;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idHall")
    private Hall hall;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idMovie")
    private Movie movie;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "projection")
    List<SeatProjectionConnection> seatList;

}


@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "seats")
public class Seat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private long seatId;

    @Column(name = "seatNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer seatNumber;

    @Column(name = "seatLetter", nullable = false)
    private String seatLetter;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "seat", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SeatProjectionConnection> projectionList;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "connections")
public class SeatProjectionConnection{

    @EmbeddedId
    private ConnectionKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("projectionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProjection")
    private Projection projection;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("seatId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "idSeat")
    private Seat seat;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "seatProjectionConnection")
    private Ticket ticket;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "empty")
    private String status;
```

}

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class ConnectionKey  implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "projectionId")
    UUID projectionId;

    @Column(name = "seatId")
    Long seatId;
}
```

Comment: what is the error code? what is the console output?

Comment: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table `connections` add constraint `FK9cbieptb4tyq1k3nr5ac82rfm` foreign key (`id_projection`) references `projections` (`id`)" via JDBC Statement

**This error  for the FK in the related tables also.**

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table `connections` (`id_projection` binary(255) not null, `id_seat` bigint not null, `status` `empty` not null, primary key (`id_projection`, `id_seat`)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

**This error for users too.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to set up a new project I saw that for mysql dialect I accidently put MySQL8Dialect instead of 5 and mysql doesn't support using column definition in entities.

Answer (score 0):

Your table connections does not have any column `projection_id` that you are trying to use in the `CONSTRAINT pk_connections PRIMARY KEY (projection_id, seat_id)`.

Probabbly you want this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE connections (
                             id CHAR (50) NOT NULL ,
                             id_projection CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                             id_seat CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                             id_ticket CHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                             status CHAR (25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "empty",
                             CONSTRAINT pk_connections PRIMARY KEY (id_projection , id_seat ) /*sta stavit posto je slozeni kljuc*/
);
```

Comment: I think you missed it in my code bcs it is already what you wrote.

Comment: Check contraint line. You have this: CONSTRAINT pk_connections PRIMARY KEY (projection_id, seat_id). The correct one is CONSTRAINT pk_connections PRIMARY KEY (id_projection , id_seat ). Your table connections does not have projection_id column. It has a id_projection column.

Comment: I noticed in the constraint lines i put only id instead of entityname_id so i fixed that and what you said but i still have the same errors

Comment: How do you create the database schema? Using a script or letting hibernate do the creation? Where is the error exactly occurring?

Comment: The error happens when I start up my app. I was using just hibernate and I got these error. I looked it up online it said the problem is in the order tables are created, so I made the above script but the errors are still there.